# Scrolling in UICollectionView selects wrongs cells - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have the following `UICollectionView` which is populated by an `Array` with `NSManagedObject` of type `Categories`

The problem is that when a `Cell` is selected scrolling does not function correctly. When scrolling through the `UICollectionView` other cells get selected, and deselected. Strange behaviour. I think this is because of the indexPath that is set incorrectly after scrolling? Anyway, I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours, and cannot seem to grasp it. Hopefully someone can point me in the right direction!

The fetchedCategory gets compared to the category to check if it is already selected and if they are the same the colors are inverted.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CategorySelectionCollectionCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CategoryCollectionViewCell

    if fetchedCategories[indexPath.row] == category {
        cell.categoryLabel?.text = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].name
        cell.categoryLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        cell.backgroundColor = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].iconColor as? UIColor
        collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.None)
    } else {
        cell.categoryLabel?.text = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].name
        cell.categoryLabel?.textColor = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].iconColor as UIColor
        collectionView.deselectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {        
    var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as CategoryCollectionViewCell

    cell.categoryLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    cell.backgroundColor = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].iconColor as? UIColor

    category = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row]
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView!, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if var cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
        cell.categoryLabel?.text = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].name
        cell.categoryLabel?.textColor = fetchedCategories[indexPath.row].iconColor as UIColor
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing strange about this, you get this result because you don't understand cell reuse. You should not set cell properties in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, because when that cell is reused it will appear with those changes, but now in a different place in the collection view. Instead, you should change a property in your model, check that property in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and set your UI appropriately in an if-else clause. Do some searching on this site for cell reuse; you should find many answers.

Comment: can you post an example please (swift 3) @rdelmar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to call `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and configure the cells in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` or `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` delegate methods.
Also, you shouldn't be calling `selectItemAtIndexPath` and `deselectItemAtIndexPath` from within the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method.

Instead, just keep track and toggle the state of the selected category in your select/deselect callbacks, and then don't do anything other the set up up the look of your cells in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

As the commenter pointed out, the cells are re-used, so stick to the simple way the delegate callbacks are designed to be used, and you should have much better luck.

If you need to refresh the look of the cells, do it by relying on `cellForItemAtIndexPath` being called while scrolling and using the `reloadData` and `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths` collection view methods if you need to force an update.

Comment: This in combination with the above comment was enough to make me understand it correctly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It all makes so much more sense now!